# whatsapp code old number

Tags: contacts

How can I use my whatsapp with the older number.when I put my older number it requires a code and I don't have an idea how to get the code.I lost the simcard long time ago.what can I do?

Answer (score -1):

Ryan bro..  This forum is strictly for Android related issues!  However, the only way I know you can get the code is by retrieving your lost sim card.

Comment: Kenny bro, [this site is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/286110). :)